# Setting max iteration for mintpy when using ipopt for nlp solver

Tags: pyomo

I've been trying to figure out how to set the iteration count for the ipopt solver for the past hour, and I can't figure it out from the documentation

This was the best I could figure out, but it still doesn't work.

```
results=SolverFactory('mindtpy').solve(instance, mip_solver='cplex', nlp_solver='ipopt',tee=True,nlp_solver_args={'nlp_iter':10000})
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me how to set the iteration counter properly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question:

I found out you can make a file ipopt.opt

and in it I put

```
# This is a comment
# Turn off the NLP scaling
#nlp_scaling_method none
# Change the initial barrier parameter
#mu_init 1e-2
# Set the max number of iterations
max_iter 10000
```

and it works great. Looks like one can set all parameters for an ipopt run with this file (it has to exist within the directory that the ipopt call is being made to be picked up)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial for ipopt.opt options at [Andreas Wächter's paper](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2009/2089/pdf/09061.WaechterAndreas.Paper.2089.pdf).

You could extend your search by introducing more parameters depending on your problem's nature.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).